# Resetting delayed job worker after deleting row from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

I'm using in heroku application delayed_job_active_record gem.

I was deleted from delayed_jobs table some job. It was already locked by worker(fields locked_by and locked_at was not blank). How can I gracefully delete locked delayed_job - and it should restart worker, that was work with current job? Because now worker is still running after deleting row.